# Handling dates and currencies in data model with Avro or Protobuf

Tags: java, apache, avro, protocol-buffers, java-money

How to handle **dates**&**currencies** in my data model with Apache Avro or Google Protobuf, can you point me to an example:

- How can I serialize and read back a Joda time Datetime?
- How can I serialize and read back currency datatime?

Thank you, Oscar